# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,500' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql

This is my error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,500' to data type int.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,500' to data type int.

Above value `1,500` is an amount which should have `','` I think this `','` is giving me the error I think. Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Add the code that you are using. Specially the SQL part.

Answer (score 3):

To convert from an `nvarchar` to `int` in SQL, you need to remove the comma.  Use `'1500'` instead of `'1,500'`.  Even better, start with the actual int instead of string like as in `1500`.

Comment: but i should display my value using comma.. any solution without removing comma..

Comment: Your display should be handled by using string formatting, not by changing the source data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `int.Parse` to convert, then try using `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` flag, for instance:

```
int parsedInt= int.Parse(stringToParse, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Comment: select name,image1,price from cuedetails where price between CAST(" + a + " AS INT) and CAST(" + b + " AS INT) order by price desc

Comment: That is my sql query in the place of a im inserting 1,500.. here im getting error

Comment: As far as I understand the problem lies in the fact that SQL is unable to handle integers with thousands separator in `CAST( a AS INT)` part. Why not remove the separators before passing `a` in the query? You could try something like `a.Replace(",","");`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this

```
int x = 0;
string result = "1,500";
x = int.Parse(result, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This allows parsing number with the thousands seprator which is present in your string.

In case you need the value only for display purpose then i don't think there is any point in converting them to `int` since you already have it formatted as a string.

Comment: select name,image1,price from cuedetails where price between CAST(" + a + " AS INT) and CAST(" + b + " AS INT) order by price desc

Comment: That is my sql query in the place of a im inserting 1,500.. here im getting error

Comment: why not pass the int value after converting as above ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this issue in SQL Server or database side, you can try the below solution:
All you need to do is to first cast the value to money and then cast it to money. Below code is working fine:

```
select cast(cast('1,500' as money) as int)
```

But if you want to solve this in .Net framework side, you can try the following code which is working fine too:

```
 string s = "1,500";
 int i = Int32.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```